# Alert View in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm very new to iOS and Objective C. I have the following code to create an alert view in iOS7 for an iPhone application:

```
if ([tracker exceededGoal]){
    [UIAlertView] *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"You acheived your goal!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Use of Undeclared identifier 'alert'
>
> Expected identifier

What did I do wrong?

Comment: try `UIAlertView *alert = ...`

Comment: You don't want square brackets around your object type.

Comment: And you are probably using ARC (since this is for iOS7) - in that case ditch the last line: `[alert release];`

Comment: It would have given a compiler error for that line if he was using ARC. So if it lets you put it, then you want to keep it because you aren't using ARC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the brackets here: `UIAlertView *alert =`